# Should most recently closed tabs be hidden at the top of the list?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, tabs

I've been trying to effectively use the list of recently closed tabs in Safari in iOS (15.5) for quite some time now, but I never seem to recognize any of my most recently closed tabs there. I've then scrolled to the very top (it's a long list) where I find my more recently closed tabs.

That's confusing — "why are the recently closed tabs so inaccessible?" — but I would've just written it off as a bug...except that every time I actually test the behavior the tab I just closed is placed first (at the bottom) of the list, so that it's no longer chronological. Now I'm even more confused than before the test!

Weird. I then asked myself "how do they eventually end up at the top of the list?", so I relaunched Safari to let it reload from database and voila.

Is this intended behavior? Does this happen to everyone or has Safari entered some weird buggy state for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of recently closed tabs should start scrolled to the bottom because the most recently closed tabs should be at the bottom of the list. This allows you to quickly drag your finger from the button to the ‘first’ most recently closed tab to reopen it and then further back. Any other behaviour is a bug you should report to Apple.

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks for the confirmation.